# Transform adjacency lists to binary matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

Given a list of the locations of 1s in each row, I'm trying to find an efficient way to construct a binary matrix. Here's a small example, although I’m trying to find something that scales well -

Given a binary matrix:

```
> M <- matrix(rbinom(25,1,0.5),5,5)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    1    1    0    0
```

I can transform M into an adjacency list using:

```
> Mlist <- apply(M==1, 1, which, simplify = FALSE)
> Mlist
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 4 5

[[4]]
[1] 1 4

[[5]]
[1] 2 3
```

I'd like to transform `Mlist` back into `M`. One possibility is:

```
M.new <- matrix(0,5,5)
for (row in 1:5){M.new[row,Mlist[[row]]] <- 1}
```

But, it seems like there should be a more efficient way.

Thanks!

Comment: you could use a sparse matrix ; e.g. `sparseMatrix(i=rep(seq_along(Mlist), lengths(Mlist)), j=unlist(Mlist), x=1)`. This will likely be slower for small examples but faster for larger, more memory consuming examples

Comment: @user20650 It's a great idea (and previously suggested). I just haven't been able to identify a size for which the sparseMatrix approach is faster.

Comment: @Zachary ; I  think your method is a sensible approach. The sparse method is useful when you have large problems when a dens e matrix wont fit n memory

Comment: @Akrun; sorry ;) almost a word for word copy of what yuo wrote

Comment: @user20650 its okay.  I was surprised that the `cbind` method is slow compared to the looping

Comment: @akrun; yes even for larger problems its twice as slow. Probably need a ton more rows for your approach to be faster -- but then it is too big a problem. I think it is worth undeleting your answer to show attempts / benchmark -- it is still useful

Comment: @user20650 thanks.  I undeleted.  In case you come up with a better approach, please do post as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Using M and Mlist defined in the Note at the end, sapply over its components replacing a vector of zeros with ones at the needed locations.  Transpose at the end.

```
M2 <- t(sapply(Mlist, replace, x = integer(length(Mlist)), 1L))

identical(M, M2)  # check that M2 equals M
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** A variation with slightly more keystrokes, but faster, would be

```
M3 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(Mlist, replace, x = integer(length(Mlist)), 1L))

identical(M, M3)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Benchmark

Here ex1 and ex2 are (1) and (2) above and ex0 is the for loop in the question except we used integer instead of double.  Note that (2) is about 100x faster then the loop in the question.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  ex0 = { M.new <- matrix(0L,5,5); for (row in 1:5){M.new[row,Mlist[[row]]] <- 1L} },
  ex1 = t(sapply(Mlist, replace, x = integer(length(Mlist)), 1L)),
  ex2 = do.call("rbind", lapply(Mlist, replace, x = integer(length(Mlist)), 1L))
)
```

giving:

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq     mean median      uq    max neval cld
  ex0 4454.4 4504.15 4639.111 4564.1 4670.10 8450.2   100   b
  ex1   73.1   84.75   98.220   94.3  111.75  130.8   100  a 
  ex2   32.0   36.20   43.866   42.7   51.85   82.5   100  a
```

### Note

```
set.seed(123)
M <- matrix(rbinom(25,1,0.5),5,5)
Mlist <- apply(M==1, 1, which, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Added benchmark.

Comment: This is a clever approach, but doesn't seem to scale well for larger matrices. It's quite fast for 5x5, but slower for 1000x1000: ex0 = 2.86ms, ex1 = 7.58ms, ex2 = 4.89ms.

Answer (score 1):

Using the vectorized row/column indexing - `rep`licate the sequence of 'Mlist' by the `lengths` of the 'Mlist', and `cbind` with the `unlist`ed 'Mlist' to create a `matrix` which can be used to assign the subset of elements of 'M.new' to 1

```
ind <- cbind(rep(seq_along(Mlist), lengths(Mlist)), unlist(Mlist))
M.new[ind] <- 1
```

-checking

```
> all.equal(M, M.new)
[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another option is `sparseMatrix`

```
library(Matrix)
as.matrix(sparseMatrix(i = rep(seq_along(Mlist), lengths(Mlist)),
      j = unlist(Mlist), x = 1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    1    0
[5,]    1    0    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks! Both methods work, but they seem to have longer running times than the original method. When `M` is a 10000x10000 matrix, the indexed approach takes about 3 times longer, and the sparseMatrix approach takes about 6 times longer.